# Outlook Module Extension - Maintaining context

Tags: outlook, office365, add-in

I have a web application running in an Outlook module extension, but when a user navigates away from the add-in and back,(e.g. clicking on "mail" and then back to the add-in) the website reloads.  Is there a way to not have the embedded browser reload when moving between mail, calendar, and the module extension?